# Angular2 material expansion panel

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material2

I am developing angular2 application i am using material design **expansion panel**. I want only the arrow mark to be present. I dont want **mat-expansion-panel-header** only arrow mark should be present. Can any one please guide me to do.Here is my code. I am inserting screen shot. 
[image]
**app.component.html**

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>

  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

 <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput placeholder="First name">
 </mat-form-field>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. Your code essentially displays an expansion panel with only the arrow present (so without a title or description). So what exactly is the issue?

Comment: Hi Andrei, its displaying only arrow, but its the space it is consuming. I dont want the blank space.

Comment: Not sure that's possible with this component. What should it show when it's collapsed then? only the first line of you content, or...?

Comment: Hi Andrei, Only arrow. Click on arrow, it should expand, click on arrow it should collapse. Can you please help